# Maximo Anywhere - Configuring related objects

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I'm having issues completing what I thought would be a relatively easy configuration to one of the Maximo Anywhere apps, allowing users to view a list of records related to (in this case) the workorder object, and selecting one of the records from the list to view the details of that record. This new object is placed just below the workorder object in the object structure hierarchy.

My configurations are in line with what's described in the documentation found at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/pdf_si_mpl_customize.pdf but this document only goes as far as making it possible to view related records in a list view, which I've been able to accomplish.

The issue I'm having is that if I select any of the related records in the list view, the details view that I'm directed to, that I've created doesn't populate any of the fields with data, as in the previous list view, that uses the same resource, and is essentially set up the same way.

In an attempt to figure out what I'm doing wrong I've been taking a look at how the worklog object (that is configured out-of-the-box to behave the way that I want my new object to behave) is setup when it comes to the object structure, OSLC resource and app.xml in question. The only thing I've found is that the worklog object has an attribute named "ANYWHEREREFID" configured in Maximo, that is also defined in the app.xml itself. Does  this attribute do anything?

If anybody has experience of configuring a related object like this in any of the Maximo Anywhere apps, I'm very thankful for any suggestions.